# Commenting useState prevents crash on IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, babeljs, core-js

I uploaded [a repository](https://github.com/jeiea/unidentified-bug).

`dist/index.htm` cause a crash on IE11 like the following.

> unable to get property 'root' of undefined or null reference

```
// inner.jsx
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function Inner() {
  var [path] = useState(''); // <- why commenting this prevents crash?
  return <Grid container></Grid>;
}
```

But with commenting `var [path] = useState('')` in `src/inner.jsx` and run `npm run publish`, that crash doesn't occur. I can't understand the result.

Is it bug? if then, where should I file an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` to `useBuiltIns: 'entry'` resolves the issue with IE11.

Comment: preset-env's `useBuiltins: 'usage'` is not sufficient? It is simplified version of more complex project. Polyfill worked well.

Comment: If we merge `App` and `Inner` then crash also disappear. Even if this is polyfill problem, it's strange.

Comment: When you're importing inner you're using object spread, when you use the useState hook, you are using array spread. IE11 need polyfills for handling spread :)

Comment: I uploaded [polyfill POC](https://github.com/jeiea/unidentified-bug/tree/ie-polyfill) version. I didn't touch any build configuration. It runs on IE11 with no crash.

Comment: Nice. I tend to use `facebook/create-react-app` with and without IE11 polyfills (as described in their docs).

Comment: Anyway my curiosity is not solved. Polyfill wasn't issue. But crash occurs. Then what's the problem?

Comment: I tried switching from `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` to `useBuiltIns: 'entry'` and it solved the problem for IE11. So polyfills were not added for IE. As I said, I mainly use CRA, which lets you code instead of configure ;)

Comment: Yeah, but CRA is just an option. Choice is free.I investigated more and found polyfill is injected but order is being awkward. Did you know? `entry` method is working by using no symbol polyfill :P.